# Is it possible to get all the functionality of NSTextTable inside an NSView (instead of an NSTextView)?

Tags: cocoa, swift, nsview, appkit

`NSTextTable` and associated classes `NSTextTableBlock` are mainly discussed in Apple Documentation in the context of an `NSTextView`.

Is it possible to get the full functionality of `NSTextTable` and friends within an `NSView` container instead? I ask because I am seeing strange results when attaching an appropriately formatted `NSAttributedString` to an `NSView`. See code below:

```
class View: NSView {

@IBOutlet weak var controller:ViewController!

var textStorage:NSTextStorage!
var layoutManager:NSLayoutManager!
var textContainer:NSTextContainer!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.textStorage = NSTextStorage()
    self.layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    self.textContainer = NSTextContainer(containerSize: self.frame.size)
    self.textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
    self.layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    self.textStorage.appendAttributedString(self.controller.tableString)
}

override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

    layoutManager.ensureLayoutForTextContainer(textContainer)
    let glyphRange = layoutManager.glyphRangeForTextContainer(textContainer)
    println(textStorage.string)
    println(glyphRange)
    layoutManager.drawGlyphsForGlyphRange(glyphRange, atPoint: NSMakePoint(10, 10))
}


override var flipped:Bool{
    return true
}
```

}

**What works: ** the text in the cells are drawn
**What doesn't work: ** the background & borders are not drawn

Following the same process (same appropriately formatted `NSAttributableString`) with an `NSTextView` does draw the background and borders. The `NSTextView` process is much simpler as you only need to attach the `NSTextStorage` object.

Comment: Why is this Q tagged with Objective-C?

Comment: Swift is very new and I have found that the group of people with the deepest knowledge of AppKit APIs are the Objective-C coders.

Comment: That is not the meaning of a tag. Add Cocoa instead ans remove objective-c.